# ConstraintLayout inside ScrollView root not working as expected

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` inside a `ScrollView` which is the root view of my layout. I wanted the ScrollView to kick in scrolling as soon as the height of the device is less than that is required for the layout.

My layout xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.clickagee.babybind.AccountSettingActivity"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_account_title"
        style="@style/textXLargePurple"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:text="@string/account"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_partner"
        style="@style/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_purple_outline"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:text="@string/add_partner"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_account_title"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_account_title" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_upload_change_photo_pane"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_size_large"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_add_partner">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/civ_change_upload_photo"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_upload_user_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_upload_change_photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/upload_photo" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_upload_change_photo_pane">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_user_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/name_hint"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_gender_account_setting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_size_small"
        android:text="@string/gender"
        android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_user_name" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg_user_gender"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_size_small"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_gender_account_setting">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_user_male_account_settings"
            style="@style/textLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button_male"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_size_small"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
            android:text="@string/male"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/radio_button_text_colors" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_user_female_account_settings"
            style="@style/textLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button_female"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_size_small"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
            android:text="@string/female"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/radio_button_text_colors" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_user_other_account_settings"
            style="@style/textLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button_other"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_size_small"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
            android:text="@string/other"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/radio_button_text_colors" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_user_phone_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rg_user_gender">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_user_phone_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
            android:hint="@string/phone_number_hint"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_user_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_user_phone_number">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_user_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email_hint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_save_details_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_size_large"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_user_email">
          <br.com.simplepass.loading_button_lib.customViews.CircularProgressButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_save_details"
            style="@style/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_size_small"
            android:text="@string/save_details"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:spinning_bar_color="@color/white"
            app:spinning_bar_padding="@dimen/spinning_bar_padding"
            app:spinning_bar_width="@dimen/spinning_bar_width" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel_account_settings"
        style="@style/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_purple_outline"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_size_small"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_save_details_ll"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_padding_size_small"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

But instead I am getting scroll whether the required height is less or not.

A screenshot of this unusual behavior is [image]

The following should not have happened, Am I missing anything here?:
[image]

Comment: I checked your code in my project it's layout is working perfectly. It's not overscrolling. Can you please be more specific about the problem

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi The problem is exactly that it is overscrolling. For screens that can accommodate this height, it should not have scrolled but it scrolls no matter the height of the screen. I wonder how this exact code could be working.

Comment: I wonder if it has got something to do with my `ConstarintLayout` version. What `ConstraintLayout` version are you using @BrijeshJoshi ?

Comment: I'm using `1.1.2`.

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi Using `1.1.2` did not solve this particular issue for me but it did broke other layouts for me. I don't know what the issue is with this layout

Comment: Ha ha.. Please provide that code. Let's see if we can help

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi I have provided the code in the question and never mind i used combinations of `LinearLayout`s and `Relativelayout`s to achieve the same layout.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` to your `btn_cancel_account_settings`

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel_account_settings"
        style="@style/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_purple_outline"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_size_small"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_save_details_ll"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_padding_size_small"/>
```

Comment: Doing so will just add a constraint on the Cancel Button to be on the bottom of save button and on Top of bottom parent. I did try this before posting.  See what adding this `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" ` does [here](https://imgur.com/a/bhGxUyy)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: No good man. Not working. I would have banged my head to the table if this was causing the problem. Plus using `match_parent` on the `ConstraintLayout` produces a lint warning.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your text input field has default focus. Give up the focus from input text field and add the following property: `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` to `btn_cancel_account_settings`.

Comment: What do you mean by, my `EditText` has default foucus. The lines `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in the `ScrollView` prevents the descendants view from gaining focus at the start. 
Also adding `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the Cancel button produced [this](https://imgur.com/a/bhGxUyy) result.